# Mapping two dimensions array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-apps-script, map-function

With an input of a 2 dimensions array I need to get as output an array with the elements in uppercase.

This is my try, but it doesn't works.

```
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila', 'avila', 'burgos', 'madrid', 'sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];


console.log(cityRow);
function upperCaseArray(myArray) {
  var upperized = myArray.map(function(city){
    console.log(typeof city);
    return city.toUpperCase();
  });
  return upperized;
}

console.log(upperCaseArray(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityRow));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityCell));
// output desired:
// [['AVILA], ['BURGOS'], ['MADRID'], ['SEVILLA']]
// [['AVILA, 'AVILA', 'BURGOS', 'MADRID', SEVILLA']]
// [['SEVILLA']]
```

Note:  thesee inputs are that I've get from a Google Sheet range `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection().getActiveRange().getValues()`.  I'm starting coding Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your strings are nested inside arrays which are inside arrays themselves, you need *two* `.map`s:

```js
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila', 'avila', 'burgos', 'madrid', 'sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];
function upperCaseArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(subarr) {
    return subarr.map(function(str) {
      return str.toUpperCase();
    });
  });
}
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityRow));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityCell));
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your elements in the arrays need to be enclosed with quotes `"` or `'` to mark them as strings, otherwise the interpretator will see them as undefined variables.

You can use the `map` function to apply a function to all elements in an array. But since this is a 2 dimensional array you need to apply it in a nested way, like the following:

```js
var cityColumn = [["avila"], ["burgos"], ["madrid"], ["sevilla"]];
var cityRow = [["avila", "avila", "burgos", "madrid", "sevilla"]];
var cityCell = [["sevilla"]];

function arrUpper(arr) {
    // o as in outer, and i as in inner
    return arr.map(o => o.map(i => i.toUpperCase()));
}

console.log(arrUpper(cityColumn));
console.log(arrUpper(cityRow));
console.log(arrUpper(cityCell));
```

**Output**

```
[["AVILA"], ["BURGOS"], ["MADRID"], ["SEVILLA"]]
[["AVILA", "AVILA", "BURGOS", "MADRID", "SEVILLA"]]
[["SEVILLA"]]
```

Comment: IIRC, Rhino (GAS) doesn't support ES6 syntax, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila, avila, burgos, madrid, sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];


console.log(cityRow);
function upperCaseArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => a.map(item => item.toUpperCase()));
  }

console.log(upperCaseArray(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityRow));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityCell));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add single quotes to strings.

```js
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila, avila, burgos, madrid, sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];


console.log(cityRow);
function upperCaseArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(a => a.map(item => item.toUpperCase()));
  }

console.log(upperCaseArray(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityRow));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityCell));
```

Comment: IIRC, Rhino (GAS) doesn't support ES6 syntax, unfortunately

Comment: I'm not following. Why should it support Rhino (GAS)?

Comment: Because OP is using GAS (which runs on Rhino)

Answer (score 1):

You can `join()` the array to make the array as a string. Then upper case the string. Finally `split()` them to from the array again.

Change

```
return city.toUpperCase();
```

To

```
return city.join(',').toUpperCase().split(',');
```

```js
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila', 'avila', 'burgos', 'madrid', 'sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];

function upperCaseArray(myArray) {
  var upperized = myArray.map(function(city){
    return city.join(',').toUpperCase().split(',');
  });
  return upperized;
}

console.log(upperCaseArray(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityRow));
console.log(upperCaseArray(cityCell));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` recursively.

```
function toUpper(arr){
  if(arr.map){
   return arr.map(toUpper);
  } else {
   return arr.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

Recursion depth for a two dimensional array is 2. GAS supports upto 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to create arrays with uppercase strings:

```js
let cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
let cityRow = [['avila', 'avila', 'burgos', 'madrid', 'sevilla']];
let cityCell = [['sevilla']];

function upperCase(arr) {
   return arr.map(function(a) {
      return a.map(function(s) { return s.toUpperCase(); });
   });
};

console.log(upperCase(cityColumn));
console.log(upperCase(cityRow));
console.log(upperCase(cityCell));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for the input. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cityColumn = [['avila'], ['burgos'], ['madrid'], ['sevilla']];
var cityRow = [['avila', 'avila', 'burgos', 'madrid', 'sevilla']];
var cityCell = [['sevilla']];

function parseData(input){
        return input.reduce(function(o,i){
            return i.reduce(function(oo,ii){
                oo.push(ii.toUpperCase());
                return oo;
            },[]);
        },[]);
    }

console.log(parseData(cityCell));
console.log(parseData(cityRow));
console.log(parseData(cityColumn));
```

Comment: `.map` is probably more appropriate than `reduce` when you're transforming every element in one array into an element in another array

Comment: `.map` will change the original object itself that not what you want.

Comment: No, `.map` does not mutate the original array. (none of the array methods mutate except for splice, push, pop, shift, unshift, sort, reverse IIRC)

Comment: if it's not mutate then it will also create the new object

Comment: @CertainPerformance In terms of performance both are more or less same. Better to go with for loop. Found same good performance metrics on github https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS . Have a look into it.